# If my project is using code (App.cs vs. App.Xaml), can I have a style defined in Xaml that I can reference in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to customize the appearance of the Picker in UWP (I want to remove the dropdown arrow), and I have a control template defined in the UWP App.Xaml, similar to:

```
<Application
    x:Class="StoreFulfillment.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StoreFulfillment.UWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Name="PickerStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Grid>
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And in my picker custom renderer, I want to set the `Style` property of the Picker UWP control (which is a ComboBox) to the PickerStyle defined in the Xaml, something like this:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Control.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)Application.Current.Resources["PickerStyle"];
}
```

But `Application.Current.Resources` does not contain the style I've defined in the Xaml. How do I reference it or access it from the custom renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `x:Key` attribute on `Style` for it to be retrieved like that. You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#look-up-resources-in-code).

```
<Style x:Key="PickerStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Resources can have either a `Key` or a `Name`. Specifying both is not recommended. In your case - you can simply say `Control.Style = this.PickerStyle;` if `Control` is defined in `Application`. If it's in a different page you might be able to do `Control.Style = ((App)Application.Current).PickerStyle;` If you'd rather use resource keys - follow G's answer.